# what regular expression [[:space:][:digit:]]+ stands for in r

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to find out what is this regular expression `[[:space:][:digit:]]+` stands for.

I learn from Wikipedia that `[:space:]` means Whitespace characters and `[:digit:]` means Digits from 0 to 9.

So I think `[[:space:][:digit:]]+` matches any Whitespace characters followed by a digit like  ' 1' or ' 9'.

But, when I try this in r:

```
> txt <- c("arm","foot","lefroo", "laura ")
> i <- grep("[[:space:][:digit:]]+", txt)
> txt[i]
[1] "laura "
```

there is no digit in "laura ", but it sill matched.

this really confused me, any one can explain this?

Comment: `[[:space:][:digit:]]+` means 1 or more whitespace or/and digits and `"laura "` contains a space. What is the problem?

Comment: I linked to posts to this one, if they are not enough to clear it out, let know.